# What is the best Python library to get morphemes (including the stem) from a word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, nlp, polyglot

I'm currently using the Polyglot library, however I would to be able to break down words like `writing` into `write` and `ing`. Polyglot is able to break down words like `reading` successfully into `read` and `ing`, but it fails when the stem is word written differently, as in `writing` or `unbelievable`.

Are there any libraries out there that could accomplish what I need?

Comment: If you're for a stem words package [nltk.stem package](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html)

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking for a package that extracts morphemes from words. So, for example, I'd like to extract `write` and `ing` from the word `writing`.

Comment: @Dominique Hey Dominique. While I don't have the answer to your question, I am also looking for a python library that can break down words into their morphemes. Have you had any luck in this yet? If not, how have you used the polyglot library to do this? I'd really appreciate if you'd let me know for I have a project that is counting on this.

Comment: @MarcelinoVelasquez Hey, unfortunately I never found a solution for this an another dev took over the task.

Comment: @Dominique there is a python library https://github.com/ecscstatsconsulting/morphemes that might be helpful to you